# Save and name the set of tabs in a single Firefox window

Tags: tabs, bookmarks, firefox-extensions

I bounce back and forth between three to ten projects on which I am doing research, and I often have 20 to 50 tabs open on each project. As a result I usually have 100 to 200 tabs open at a time. This is a major drain on memory and creates instability. I would like to find a way in Firefox 3 or 4 to quickly and easily save all the tabs in a single window without saving all the other tabs, assign that group of tabs a name, and reopen named groups of tabs in a single window - as if the tabs in a given window were in a folder that you could save and reopen. Ideally, I would like to be able to open and close tabs in a window and then save the group to the same name and have the altered group open next time. And it should not interfere with the ability of the session manager to save and reopen all my tabs in every window when I quit for the day or if the session crashes.

Is there any way to do this in a standalone copy of Firefox 3 or 4? If not, is there an add-on or extension that allows you to do it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Andrew

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using [Tab groups](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/what-are-tab-groups?s=tab%20groups&as=s)?

Comment: Tab groups is what you're looking for.

Comment: For Google Chrome, there's an extension called "Tab Cloud" that synchronizes tab groups between all Chrome installations - does anything like this exist for Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Session Manager](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=831545). It may have the options you need. Maybe not *exactly* the way you want it, but pretty close.

If the dynamic session requirement can be worked around, saving all Tabs to a bookmark folder, and then re-opening them with "Open All in Tabs" is a no-extension alternative.

Comment: I have looked at tab groups, as @DanH suggests, and I do have, and use, session manager. But I have not yet found a way to save one tab group without saving all the tab groups, and I do not see a way to open a closed tab group in a new new browser session. Since my goal is to be able to quickly save bunches of tabs, and then have access to them without having to keep them open, none of my current solutions are working for me. I suspect there is a way to, for example, bookmark a tab group, but I have not found it.

Answer (score 0):

Try right-clicking on any window with several tabs open, and select "Bookmark all tabs".
Save these in an appropriately named folder in Bookmarks.
Close the window.
When you want them back open the bookmarks menu, go to the folder and select "Open all in tabs"
Works great for me with smaller numbers of tabs, but there is no reason why you can't have many many folders saved